# Gatling: how to execute the first request only once?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I'm trying to run a scenario which has 2 requests

- The first one authenticates the users through an API and gets a token. I want each user to do the first request only once.
- The second one executes a GET throught another API.

Here's the code of the scenario:

```
val slot: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Get slot")
    .doIf(_("connected").asOption[String].isEmpty) {
      exec(
        http("Get_token")
          .post(my_endpoint)
          .headers(specific_headers)
          .formParam("username", "my_username")
          .formParam("password", "my_password")
          .check(regex("""id_token":"(.*?)"""").saveAs("my_token"))
      )
        .exec { session =>
          println("Before: " + session("connected").as[String]) //prints nothing as expected
          session
        }
        .exec(_.set("connected", "true"))
        .exec { session =>
          println("After: " + session("connected").as[String]) //prints "true" as expected
          session
        }
    }
    .feed(fsid)
    .exec(
      http("Get_slot")
        .get("/slots")
        .headers(other_specific_headers) //including "my_token" extraced above
        .queryParam("specific_id", "${specific_id}") //from feeder fsid
        .check(regex("""id":"(.*?)"""").findRandom.saveAs("slot_id"))
    )
```

Here's the code of the simulation:

```
setUp(
    slot.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(1).during(15.seconds)
    ).protocols(httpConfig)
  )
```

When I execute the above simulation, I can see in the logs that each of the 2 requests are both executed 15 times. I'm expecting to have less "Get_token" executed than "Get_slot".

I've read some documentation avout [Gatling's forever element](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#forever), and I think it could do the work.
But I would like to understand why this does not behave as I expect.

If both requests are executed 15 times, does it mean that:

- 15 users are launched, and thus their session is empty at the beginning, so it's normal they do the get_token ?
- My "Doif" is not well written ?
- Something else I'm missing ?

Any help would be great, thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Just to give more informations, according to simpleApp's comment, I only see 2 actives users during the test  (in average)
[image]

This is why I expect to see 4 "Get_token", and not more.

Comment: this looks okay to me. your simulation is to add 1 user every second for 15 seconds - so 15 users, these are unique 15 users, so each user needs their own token before making a Get_slot.

Comment: @simpleApp the thing is, when I look the Gatling report, I can see there's 1 active user during the test, not 15. You think that every second, a new user is started and stopped after doing its request ? Thx in advance

Comment: you are seeing only 1 active user, as your users are not staying in the system for quite a good time. For example, if you keep a pause ` .pause(20) ` at the last action on your user interaction, then you will notice that your active users are at 15. In this situation, your request and user will be at 15, and the "Active Users" graph will give you better visualization. i hope this makes sense to you.